# Cs50 greedy without using <cs50.h>

Tags: c, cs50

I am solving the greedy algorithm of from the cs50 course without using the cs50 header file. I have written some code. It works fine with numbers as input but when I give it a string or chars as input, it does not prompt me back. I do not know how to solve this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float c;
    int C, nQ, rem1, nD, rem2, nN, rem3;

    do
    {
        printf("O hai! How much change is owed? ");
        scanf("%f", &c);
    }
    while(c<0);

    C = c * 100;

    nQ = C / 25;
    rem1 = C % 25;

    nD = rem1 / 10;
    rem2 = rem1 % 10;

    nN = rem2 / 5;
    rem3 = rem2 % 5;

    printf("%d\n", nQ+nD+nN+rem3);
}
```

Comment: Why would you use variables named `C` and `c` in the same function?

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf("%f", &c);` to know whether 1 number was read.

Comment: I used two variables to convert the floating point into integer. I checked the values. It works fine when I input numbers. But I want to get a prompt even if I input alphabets.

Comment: `c=-1;if(scanf("%f", &c) != 1) while(getchar()!='\n');`

Comment: What output do you expect for what input? Show us an example.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the input could be separated by whitespaces. Why not `scanf("%*s")`?

Comment: O hai! How much change is owed? -5    O hai! How much change is owed? -4      O hai! How much change is owed? 4      16     O hai! How much change is owed? shshsrjh    0..............  This is the result I am getting. If I give a negative number as an input it prompts back but if I give alphabets as input it returns 0. I want it to prompt back even if I give alphabets as input.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Anything is fine.

Comment: @Laxman can you check if the answer I have posted works for you?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY any pointers to which part has a issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a float cannot accept a string. You are expecting `c` to hold other data types when it is just a float variable.

I would suggest you to take input as a string and use `atof()` to check whether the input is a floating type or not. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float c;
    int C, nQ, rem1, nD, rem2, nN, rem3;
    char str[10];

    do
    {
        printf("O hai! How much change is owed? ");
        scanf("%s", str);
    }
    while(atof(str) > 0);
    c = atof(str);
    C = c * 100;

    nQ = C / 25;
    rem1 = C % 25;

    nD = rem1 / 10;
    rem2 = rem1 % 10;

    nN = rem2 / 5;
    rem3 = rem2 % 5;

    printf("%d\n", nQ+nD+nN+rem3);
}
```

This makes sure that you are using a do while loop only for floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `c` to be negative after your entered a sequence that is not a floating point number.

This is not a valid assumption. If `scanf` fails, the value of the variable read is undefined.

You need to check the return value of `scanf` to know if the read was indeed successful. So you can change the code to.

```
int read;
do
{
    printf("O hai! How much change is owed? ");
    read = scanf("%f", &c);

    if (read == EOF){
        // Appropriate error message.
        return -1;
    }
    if (read != 1)
        scanf("%*s");
}
while(read != 1 || c < 0);
```

Now, if the scanf doesn't read a float, it will return 0 and you can continue prompting.

Demo [here](https://ideone.com/SCRL67)

Comment: I had missed the part where I need to discard the string in case the float is not read. Edited and added.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Your demo code works. Thank you.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think that was the required behavior - OP wants a re prompt if the input is negative.

Comment: I checked it now. The code works fine. Even I had the same problem. But now it just prompts once.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY changed order of operands to `||`.